# Problems with Azure AD response with OAuth implicit flow

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory

I tried to follow the OAuth implicit flow as mentioned in [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code) doc
and it works fine.

But when i changed the response_type to 'token', azure ad redirects back to `https://example.com/#access_token=ey...` instead of `https://example.com/?access_token=ey...`

Difference is the `#` instead of `?`. This is a problem as we are not able to fetch the parameter using

```
Request.Params.Get("access_token"); //this always null
```

How to fetch the access token from the url?

Comment: i want to do it in C#. is there any way than to perform string manipulations on the full url. We were trying to avoid the manipulations on the url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a trap!

You can't do it in the backend.

That's the whole point of it being a fragment rather than a parameter - only the user agent can extract it. Use `adal.js` or manually extract it in JavaScript and place in local/session storage.

Follow the samples in [azure-activedirectory-library-for-js](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js) and look at [this method](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/blob/703e560f26de90fef9ae955529605672242c1f71/lib/adal.js#L1302).